# Number of moves required to create a 5×5 chessboard under the given conditions

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, maxima-minima, coloring, chessboard

Consider a 5×5 square divided into 25 cells. Initially all cells are white. In each move it is allowed to change the colour of any three consecutive cells in a row or column to the opposite colour (i.e. white cells become black and black ones become white). What is the minimum possible number of moves needed to obtain the chessboard colouring shown in the figure?

[image]

A friend and I were able to show that 16 moves can create the chessboard under the given conditions. However, we weren't able to prove that 16 is the minimum possible number of moves that can create the chessboard. Upon checking the internet for possible solutions to the problem, we found out that the minimum possible number of moves is less than 10, according to the answer key accompanying the exam from which the question was extracted (KSF 2016, Student Level, Question 29). However, we have no idea how this answer was obtained.

Comment: In fact, it looks like you can do with $8$ moves: flip the colour of the following $3\times 1$ rectangles: $[A_2A_3A_4], [B_5C_5D_5], [E_2E_3E_4], [B_1C_1D_1], [A_3B_3C_3], [C_3C_4C_5], [C_1C_2C_3], [C_3D_3E_3]$ (assuming the board is labelled as in chess). Whether this is the minimum - I don't know.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  How did you find that ?

Comment: @Peter Trial and error.

Comment: Brute force for $7$ moves should then clarify whether we can do even better.

Comment: We will need an even number of moves, so we only need to show that it cannot be done in $6$ moves (which is quite easy ?)... & then Stinky Bishops $8$ move is seen to be minimal.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit  Why must the number of moves we need be even?

Comment: Put numbers in the squares to indicate how many times they have been toggled. We need to toggle the $12$ black squares & then we can add only even values to any square. Each move adds $3$ to the sum of the values ... so we will need to do moves in $2$s.